# Rhythmbox doesn't close in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: rhythmbox, 17.10

When I close rhythmbox with the X in the corner, the music continues to play and there is no sign of rhythmbox in the top bar either. How do I close rhythmbox in the new look in Ubuntu 17.10?

The only workaround I can find is in the console type

```
killall rhythmbox
```

Also it seems like rhythmbox crashes quite often with the message

```
(rhythmbox:31863): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_view_update_button_position: assertion 'column_el != NULL' failed
```

But I am not sure, if that has to do something with the missing close functionality, it more seems to be a global bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1689927

Comment: Thanks for `killall rhythmbox`. I would add `sudo apt-get remove --purge rhythmbox` and `sudo apt-get install -y vlc`.  If only Ubuntu developers knew about the Least Surprise Principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not new behavior for Rhythmbox, as it has been this way in Ubuntu for several years now. To quit, you first need to stop the music playback.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the app launcher and click **Stop & Quit**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also close Rhythmbox with the keyboard command Crtl + Q.

Besides, I am not a big fan of this behaviour either and I think it is irritating.